# Finding vertical asymptotes

Tags: calculus, limits

So I am trying to find the behaviour of this function around an asymptote at $x=0$.

$a>0$

$$y=\frac{(x-a)(x^2+a)}{x^2}$$

I know that as $x \to 0^+$, $y \to -\infty $ and $x \to 0^-$, $y \to -\infty $.

I've tried dividing the top and bottom of $y$ by $x^2$ and ended with:

$$x-a+\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a^2}{x^2}$$

Which does not help me as I end with $\infty -\infty$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dividing the top and bottom by a power of $x$ is a method one uses to find a limit as $x \to \pm \infty$.  Tell me first how you arrive at the correct limit $y \to -\infty$.

Comment: $$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(x-a)(x^{2}+a)}{x^{2}} &=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}%
\frac{x^{3}-ax^{2}+ax-a^{2}}{x^{2}} \\
&=&-a^{2}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}} \\
&=&-\infty 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: My apologies. The question is framed around identifying the functions that match graphs of functions with asymptotes. There were three in total - I have successfully solved the first two. So I know the general behaviour of this function.

Comment: What description of the behavior are you looking for?  From your equation $y=x-a+\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a^2}{x^2}$ you can see that as $x$ approaches $0$ the last term will dominate.  The fact that the numerator of that term (including the leading sign) is negative supports your claim that it goes to $-\infty$ whichever side of $0\ \ x$ is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment above.

> I know that as $x \to 0^+$, $y \to -\infty $ and $x \to 0^-$, $y \to
>  -\infty $.

Only the first assertion is correct.

Since $\left( x-a\right) (x^{2}+a)=x^{3}-ax^{2}+ax-a^{2}$, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left( x-a\right) (x^{2}+a)}{x^{2}}
&=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( x^{3}-ax^{2}+ax-a^{2}\right) \times
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}} \\
&=&-a^{2}\times \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}=-a^{2}\left( +\infty
\right) =-\infty, \qquad\text{    for }a\ne 0.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So as $x$ approaches $0$, either from the left or from the right, $y\rightarrow -\infty $. The limit does not depend on the sign of $a$.

Plot of $y$ for $a=1$ (black) and $a=-1$ (green).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $x-a$ is negative when $x$ is near $0$ and $x^2 + a$ positive is positive when $x$ is near zero, and the denominator is positive, will mean that the function must approach $-\infty$ at the vertical asymptote, *unless* the numerator also approaches $0$, in which case you've got more work to do.  In this case the numerator approaches $-a^3$, which is not $0$, so that's it.

You're quite right about the fact that breaking it into $\infty-\infty$ won't help.  If you had that, I'd tell you to write it as a single fraction by using a common denominator.  That would take you to what you started with.